# How to return a key=>value pair from a function in PHP

Tags: php, return-value, key-value

I need to return a key value pair from a function. It would be preferable to retain the structure of the data. I would like to avoid creating an array with only one value if possible as I do not care for the syntax `key($result[0])` or an array with two values, as I would like something with a syntax or structure that suggests the key=>value relationship between the values. Is there a more elegant alternative to the array for returning multiple values from a function in php?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, Arrays are pretty elegant in my opinion,

Comment: `list()` might be a bit nicer: `list($key, $val) = myfunc();`. Still requires that you return an array from your function though

Comment: What would be your preferred return format if not an array? If in an array you will either have to call key() or create an array with the key in one slot and the value in another Array("key" => $key, "val" = $val)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
function getData () {
  return array('key','value');
}

list($key,$value) = getData();
echo $key." = ".$value;
```

Although I must say, this sounds like a bizarrely specific and largely cosmetic requirement...

Comment: The function is part of a wrapper around an API which returns the result of every request in a deeply nested array structure. I am trying to remove as many layers of pointless nesting as possible and create a single array of $service_token=>$status pairs. When a new token is added the response from the server comes back (as a crazy nested array structure). The point of my class is to eliminate the nested arrays. It seems silly to unpack the data from two nested arrays in order to pack it back into an array. I guess that is "cosmetic", but not really "bizarre". Why so "judgemental"?

Comment: @SinthiaV That is a fair comment, but equally if you had added that information to the question it may not have invited the incredulous answers/comments that have been banded about... It's always worth adding as much (relevant) information as you can to the question, as it can often result in someone giving you a whole new approach to the problem as a whole, rather than just a solution to one specific part of it. But I do take your point about making throw-away comments as part of answers, and I shall +1 your comment to show no bad feelings :-D

Comment: And I accepted your answer, as it actually would make sense to use a list one step further back when I am extracting the useful data from the arrays.

Answer (score 9):

You can only use `array()`, really.

```
return array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
```

Anything else would just be uglier or more confusing.

Comment: year 2021: you could simply...
return ["key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"];

Answer (score 1):

Could you not return the values in an array, like so?

```
return array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
```

You could also do this:

```
return array($key => $value);
```

But that's involves more work to use after the fact, in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not understanding the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Return an array.

```
return array("key" => "value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a full example proposed by @polynomial that might be interesting:

```
//Function declaration with a return of a key value pair array
function getUserRating(){
  return array(
    'rating' => $rating, 
    'average'  => $average
  );
}

// Retrieve one of the key value pair 
getUserRating()['rating'];
// Retrieve the other key value pair 
getUserRating()['average'];
```

Think this kind of magic only work with PHP 7 or further? OMG! It Works with PHP 5.4!

Answer (score -1):

Am I misunderstanding your question, or do you not want `return array('aKey' => 'aVal');`?

Comment: You could have at least provided your reasoning for the downvote and given me a chance to help. This answer is no different than 3 others that were posted.

Comment: I'm guessing it was probably bad luck, although looking at the other two similar answers, it's possible that your answer was interpreted as "intended as a comment".  I didn't cast the downvote; just speculating.

Comment: It's not a big deal - just annoying.