# Get Specific Key/Value Pairs from array by mentioning keys

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a method is core php by which I can Get Specific Key/Value Pairs from array by mentioning keys. Like

```
$my_array=['foo1'=>'bar1', 'foo2'=>'bar2', 'foo3'=>'bar3'];
```

Now I wanted to call a function which will input array name and keys and output those key/pairs as new array.

```
doMagic($my_array, ['foo1', 'foo3']) -> ['foo1'=>'bar1', 'foo3'=>'bar3']
```

There is a similar thing in Laravel on request object when we do in the controller

```
$request->only('foo1', 'foo3') -> it returns an array
```

I need similar thing in core php, on an array not object. Is there a function available in core php for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a key=>value pair from a function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347977/how-to-return-a-key-value-pair-from-a-function-in-php)

Comment: How strange everyone giving ditto answers :P

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by using array filter in php like this :-

```
$my_array=['foo1'=>'bar1', 'foo2'=>'bar2', 'foo3'=>'bar3'];

$only = ['foo1','foo3'];

var_dump(array_filter($my_array, function($k)  use ($only) {
    return in_array($k,$only);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

this is the output :-

```
array(2) {
  ["foo1"]=>
  string(4) "bar1"
  ["foo3"]=>
  string(4) "bar3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with [`ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/array.constants.php#constant.array-filter-use-key) constant in combination with [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array):

```
$my_array=['foo1'=>'bar1', 'foo2'=>'bar2', 'foo3'=>'bar3'];
$keys = ['foo1', 'foo3'];
$res = array_filter($my_array, function($key) use($keys) {
    return in_array($key, $keys);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an associative array in PHP, you can do:

```
$my_array = array("foo1"=>"bar1", "foo2"=>"bar2", "foo3"=>"bar3");
```

To filter unwanted values you can do:

```
function doMagic($my_array, $filter) {
    array_filter($my_array, function($key) use($filter) {
         return in_array($key, $keys);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
```